# How are processes described in Ubuntu?

Tags: process

I need to know in detail how are processes described in Ubuntu? I have tried Google, but no luck. As I require it for research purposes, please help. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: You are required to research any operating system(Ubuntu in my case). Your research must include the following with reference to the OS you are describing:
Process description and control
 What process states are available
( How are processes described)
 How are processes controlled
 Is the OS treated as a process or not
 Security issues

Comment: everything in linux is a file. So with every process there is a directory in /proc named with the process id of the particular process. then there are many files in that directory which store different things like memory map of process. processor scheduling info etc resource allocation tables etc. more info at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/kernel/processes.html

Comment: @shivgarg  The correct directory is `/proc` , there's no `/etc/proc`

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I meant to say /proc

Comment: @rish This is a very broad topic that you have. There's whole books written on the topic of processes. shivgard properly noted that Linux has `/proc` directory which has information on every process. You can start by researching information on `/proc` filesystem

Comment: so would the identifiers be the way ubuntu describes its processes?sorry i am not to familiar with ubunu

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubuntu but with Unix and Linux in general :-P  @shiv "file descriptor" (sockets and pipes ;-) )

Comment: @rish yes, every Linux/Unix uses PID to  identify processes. More specifically, getpid() and getppid() functions in C can be used for that

Answer (score 1):

When you issue a command or execute a shell script in *any* Unix-like operating system, you start, or create, a **process**. In short, a process is an instance of a running program. Attributes of processes include a process-id (**pid**) and a parent process-id (**ppid**), and there are others. Processes are also associated with a terminal (**tty**) from which they were executed, unless they are **daemons**.

I suggest you read more about processes and their attributes [at the Unix School](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/09/what-is-process-in-unix-linux.html) or at [these university user-pages](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~jack/ifsm498d/processes.html). (All of these pages and more were found with Google, so it is unclear why you were unable to find them.)

Answer (score 1):

In Unix , there are two things

1. files
2. Process

**"files has places and processes have life" by Kaare Christian**

A running file that is executed as a program is termed as *process* (set of instructions). Processes have children, parents, and grandchildren (no, I am not joking :) )

To see all the current processes, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter `ps`.

For more details , read Sumitabha Das, *Unix Applications* (3rd edition), section 2.5.1, and/or go to Google Books and search there, but the above book really does explain what you want.

If you really want to go more deeper, read *Modern OS* by Tanenbaum or *Operating System Concepts* by Silberschatz (but before reading these books make sure you have basics of computer organization subject; or else read *Computer System Architecture* by Morris Mano).